# What is wrong with my nginx keycloak configuration using external db with a virtual machine

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, https, keycloak

Im trying to get keycloak working on https on auth.mydomain.com using a docker-compose.yml file and nginx. I keep getting a 502 and im not sure why, keycloak is java and im no expert. Also learning docker, What am I doing wrong ?

[image: what im getting on the front end accessing auth.mydomain.com]

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
        server_name auth.mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://auth.mydomain.com/permanent;

    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
        server_name auth.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://[actualIP]:8081;

       }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: authdb.externaldb.com
      KC_DB_URL_PORT: 10000
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: db
      KC_DB_USERNAME: user
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HOSTNAME_URL: https://auth.mydomain.com
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOADK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: passwordadmin
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: https://auth.mydomain.com/admin
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 8443:8443
```

**nginx status**

```
someone@keycloak:/home/auth# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-09-19 19:45:42 UTC; 13s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 66702 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0>
    Process: 66703 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 66704 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1102)
     Memory: 3.4M
        CPU: 30ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─66704 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             └─66705 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
```

this is weird because it keeps restarting

**docker status**

```
someone@keycloak:/home/auth# docker compose ps
NAME              IMAGE                              COMMAND                     SERVICE    CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS
auth-keycloak-1   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest   "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"   keycloak   18 minutes ago   Restarting (0) 27 seconds ago
```

I trying to run keycloak in https mode using nginx and a virtual machine with an external db

Comment: the port number in real life is not 10000